# Problem installing Spring Roo in STS 4.6.1

Tags: spring-roo, spring-tool-suite

I've tried both STS 4.5.1 and STS 4.6.1, but unable to install the Spring IDE Roo Support Extension from the Nightly software site.
Error Log shows this error:

> Spring IDE Roo Support 3.9.13.202004290816-CI-B2476
>   (org.springframework.ide.eclipse.roo.feature.feature.group
>   3.9.13.202004290816-CI-B2476) requires 'org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu; org.eclipse.ajdt.feature.group 2.0.1' but it could not be found

I'm running openJDK jdk8u181-b13 on Windows 10.
Can anyone help with what needs to be done?

Comment: which nightly update site did you use? As an alternative, there is a STS3-Add-On-Pack for Spring Tools 4 for Eclipse that you can install using the Eclipse Marketplace.

Comment: I imported the sites from the bookmarks xml in the conf folder of the Spring Roo 2.0.0 Release. http://dist.springframework.org/snapshot/IDE/nightly
Just tried the Eclipse marketplace but the Add on points to https://download.springsource.com and I'm getting Unable to read repository due to certificate issues with https "Cert doesn't match alternative names..etc"

Comment: The marketplace entry is certainly the best and most accurate way of doing this, so maybe you can solve the certificate issues on SO and then use it again? Another way would be to use the non-https version of that update site, but then you would have to carefully select the right one (that works with your specific STS4 version) and select the features to install manually. I can try to write up the instructions for that as part of our STS4 user guide, but that might take some time.

Comment: I just tried importing certs into my JRE cacerts - but still doesn't work.
 I have the http version in my list of sites.I even got a plain Eclipse instance to check and same cert error.
So, 
The Eclipse Marketplace is forcing it to go to https://download.springsource.com - is there a way to override that? OR
Any other workaround for the original error above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this fixed it! The original issue I mean.
https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/1099395/

I still dont know why the https version of download.springsource.com isn't working.